# Probabilityof randomly selected nonnegative numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am supposed to solve the following problem:

What is the probability that a randomly selected nonnegative integer raised to the third gives a number that has the last two digits 75?

I figured out that $15^{3}$ has last two digits 75, then $35^{3}, 55^{3}, 75^{3}$ and so on, but I have no clue, how to solve it.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the possible two ending digits are the combinations $$15,35,55,75,95$$ the probability is $$\frac{5}{100}=\frac{1}{20}$$

Comment: The ending digits go from $00$ to $99$ , hence $100$ possibilities

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a distribution for the nonnegative integers. You may have implicitly intended to assume a uniform distribution, but there is no uniform distribution on the nonnegative integers ([Show that there is no discrete uniform distribution on N.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143866)).

The concept that’s appropriate here is not random selection but [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).

The residue of $n^3$ modulo $100$ depends only on the residue of $n$ modulo $100$, so you’ve basically already solved the problem: $15$, $35$, $55$, $75$ and $95$ are the only residues modulo $100$ whose square (modulo $100$) is $75$. There are $100$ residues modulo $100$ in all, so the natural density is $\frac5{100}=\frac1{20}$.

Comment: Why are you working with modulo 100?

Comment: @Emanuel: You wanted the last two digits. That's the residue modulo $100$.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic approach.** There is no uniform distribution on the non-negative integers, so the usual tactic is to take the limiting proportion of such integers as you examine larger and larger intervals—i.e., from $0$ to $N$ as $N \to \infty$.  If the number of such integers between $0$ and $N$ is given by $q(N)$, then the quantity you want is

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{q(N)}{N+1}
$$

where the $+1$ comes from the fact that we start with $0$ (annoyingly, since its cube clearly doesn't end in $75$).  You have hit upon the pattern matched by the required integers, so you should be able to identify the correct fraction.